# How do you change the color of a html element

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors, element

How you change the color of a html element with a click of a button
I'm making a game and need this to change the color of the player
**Edit**
Anyone who sees this in the future what I was trying to do is take a Html Element and change its color with a click of a button If you don't understand here is a visual

If you run this code It Displays A Red Box And A Button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="player" style="background:blue;height: 200px;width: 100px;">
            <button> Change Color </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below I have a normal div with a background color, height, and width. I also have a button with a onclick function that is defined in the javascript code(between the script tags). When clicking the button I'm calling the "changeCol" function. In the `changeCol` function I'm getting the div by looking for an element with the id "myDiv", and then using .`style` to specify that I want to change the style of the element, and .background to change the background color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="background:red;height: 200px;width: 100px;">
    </div>
    <button onclick="changeCol()">Click me</button>

   <script>
     function changeCol() {
         document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background = "yellow";
     }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```